# springboot jwt and oauth2 simultaneously to give access of the protected end points

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I have a spring boot application in which I have JWT authentication where a user has to enter his email and password and a token is generated. Now, I also want to give leverage to the user to login with social platform like google. Is there any way to get an access token when a user login with google and then I can use my JWT authentication to generate a token for the social login? Also, I didn’t have the front end, I am using postman but can’t find tutorials to how to demonstrate this.

I am thinking of adding form login just for oauth2 social login and then fetch the user’s access token and embed it with my custom jwt token. But is there any way to do this and how can I achieve this, do I have to create a frontend application to fetch the accesstoken and then use my custom jwt token generator ?

The below is my filter configuartion code, I cant use JWT and Social login simultaneouly as I dont have front end. I am quite confused how will I achieve this and how to store the logged in user in the database ?

```
// the below is user table 

@Entity
@Table(name = "User")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class User implements UserDetails {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "email", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String email;

    @Column
    private String password;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 150)
    private String about;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Post> posts = new ArrayList<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Comment> comments = new ArrayList<>();

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "User_role", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "roleId"))
//  @JsonManagedReference
    private Set<Role> assignedRole = new HashSet<>();

    public void addRole(Role role) {
        this.assignedRole.add(role);
        // this = user;
        role.getAssignedUser().add(this);
    }

    public void removeRole(Role role) {
        this.assignedRole.remove(role);
        role.getAssignedUser().remove(this);
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = assignedRole.stream()
                .map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName())).collect(Collectors.toList());
        return authorities;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return email;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }

}
```

```
@Configuration
@EnableMethodSecurity
@EnableWebSecurity
public class FilterConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private AuthEntryPointJwt unauthorizedHandler;

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthFilter;
    
    @Autowired
    private UserSecurity userSecurity;

    private static final String[] WHITE_LIST_URL = { "/api/auth/**","/api/users/" };

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
                .exceptionHandling(exception -> exception.authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler))
                .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .authorizeHttpRequests(req -> req.requestMatchers(WHITE_LIST_URL).permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT, "/api/users/{userId}").access(userSecurity)                        
                          .anyRequest().authenticated()
                        );
                
        http.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider);
//      http.oauth2Client(Customizer.withDefaults());
//      http.formLogin();
//      http.oauth2Login().authorizationEndpoint()
//      .baseUri("/oauth2/authorize").authorizationRequestRepository(cookieAuthorizationRequestRepository());
        http.addFilterBefore(jwtAuthFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        return http.build();
    }
    
//  @Bean
//  public SecurityFilterChain securityOAuth2FilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
//      return null;
//  }
}
```